# array_multisort seems to ignore natural sort

Tags: php, sorting

I am using PHP 5.6.6 and I have a problem with `NATURAL_SORT` in `array_multisort`.

If i do:

```
sort($var);
```

I get correct "natural" output like

```
p0_00001
p0_00002_
p0_00002_00011
p0_00002_00012
p0_00002_00013
p0_00002_00014
p0_00003_
p0_00003_00015
p0_00003_00016
p0_00003_00017
p0_00003_00018
p0_00003_00019
p0_00003_00020
p0_00003_00021
p0_00003_00022
p0_00003_00023
p0_00003_00024
p0_00004_
p0_00004_00025
```

With array_multisort, I stuck like this:

```
array_multisort($var, $foo, $bar)
```

which gives me:

```
p0_00001
p0_00002_
p0_00003_
p0_00004_
p0_00005_
p0_00006_
p0_00007_
p0_00008_
p0_00009_
p0_00010_
p0_00002_00011
p0_00002_00012
p0_00002_00013
p0_00002_00014
p0_00003_00015
p0_00003_00016
p0_00003_00017
p0_00003_00018
p0_00003_00019
p0_00003_00020
p0_00003_00021
p0_00003_00022
p0_00003_00023
p0_00003_00024
```

I tried

```
  array_multisort($var, SORT_NATURAL, $foo, $bar)
```

but the output just stays the same. I don't get it how to user `array_multisort` in order to get the "natural" output of `sort($var)`

Comment: Sorry folks, I just figured out that `$foo` and `$bar` are of different length than `$var`.... works now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
array_multisort ($var, SORT_ASC, SORT_REGULAR,
                 $var2, SORT_ASC, SORT_REGULAR,...);
```

which `$var, $var1, $var2`... are the arrays to be sorted
**Note**: these arrays are passed by reference

Comment: thx for your answer, but it doesnt sort it "natural"... My output does not change at all if "SORT_NATURAL" or/incombination "SORT_ASC" is passed or not...

Comment: i've updated my response: use `SORT_REGULAR` instead of `SORT_NATURAL`, `sort` uses `SORT_REGULAR` by default

Comment: thx very much for your efforts, but `SORT_REGULAR` won't change my output either... :/

Comment: give me your input array please :)

Comment: `$var[] = "p0_00001";`
`$var[] = "p0_00002_";`
`$var[] = "p0_00002_00011";`
`$var[] = "p0_00002_00012";`
`$var[] = "p0_00002_00013";`
`$var[] = "p0_00002_00014";`
`$var[] = "p0_00003_";`
`$var[] = "p0_00003_00015";`
`$var[] = "p0_00003_00016";`
`$var[] = "p0_00003_00017";`
`$var[] = "p0_00003_00018";`
`$var[] = "p0_00003_00019";`
`$var[] = "p0_00003_00020";`
`$var[] = "p0_00003_00021";`
`$var[] = "p0_00003_00022";`
`$var[] = "p0_00003_00023";`
`$var[] = "p0_00003_00024";`
`$var[] = "p0_00004_";`
`$var[] = "p0_00004_00025";`

`$var2 = $var;`

`sort($var);`
`array_multisort($var, $var2);`

Comment: if you var_dump($var) it works fine like you want, but $var2 will still unchanged, i don't have the answer now for why $var2 seems not to be ordered, but you can work with $var

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73070/discussion-between-halayem-anis-and-produnis).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$dataPoints1 = array('p0_00201','p3_00002_','p2_00002_00011','p0_00022_00012','p0_00002_00013','p0_00002_00014','p0_00003_');
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($dataPoints1);
    array_multisort($dataPoints1);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($dataPoints1);
```

Comment: thx man, your example showed me, that `$foo` and `$bar` are of different length than `$var`.... works now... –